# Breeze.js OData v4 Error

Tags: javascript, breeze, datajs

I am trying to create a simple JavaScript application using Breeze.js version 1.5.3. It is to consume an OData v4 service. The service is created with ASP.NET WebApi 2.

Included scripts:

```
<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/underscore.js"></script>
<script src="/js/q.js"></script>
<script src="/js/datajs-1.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="/js/breeze.debug.js"></script>
```

Here is the code configuring Breeze's EntityManager:

```
var serverAddress = "http://localhost:6405/odata/";
breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstances({ dataService: "webApiOData4" });
var manager = new breeze.EntityManager(serverAddress);
```

The code fails with the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'oData' of undefined`
Here is the snippet from `breeze.debug.js` that fails (around line 16591):

```
webApiOData4Ctor.prototype.initialize = function () {
    // Aargh... they moved the cheese.
    var datajs = core.requireLib("datajs", "Needed to support remote OData v4 services");
    OData = datajs.V4.oData; // V4 is undefined, so it throws
    OData.json.jsonHandler.recognizeDates = true;
};
```

I have searched through `datajs-1.1.3.js` and found no 'V4' symbol. Moreover the authors of this library say that it only supports OData v3. Some suggest to use `odatajs-4.0.0-beta-01.min.js` found here http://olingo.apache.org/doc/javascript/, but there is a clear dependency on `datajs` in `breeze.debug.js` source code. I have tried to include `odatajs-4.0.0-beta-01.min.js` script in my page but it has not helped.

Does anybody know how to make Breeze.js work with OData v4 service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breeze does not yet work with OData 4.0 because of a number of issues with MS OData library.  They are aware of the issues and are planning a release that fixes them soon... We are working with them and will try to release our OData 4.0 support when this happens. We will also be using the 'olingo' datajs library in order to support OData 4.0.

Note that you do NOT need OData to use breeze (especially with ASP.NET WebApi2).  See: http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/aspnet-web-api .And you actually get more capabilities and better performance if you do NOT: See http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/odata-vs-webapi

Comment: What is the possible ETA for a release supporting v4?

Comment: Thank you for information! I suppose that you fix your documentation and inform users that Breeze does not yet support OData 4.0. It will help them not to waste time trying to make it work.

Comment: @jay, Do you have an ETA for when Breeze will support Web API OData v4 please?

Comment: @Jay is there any update on the webApiOData4 yet? I suspect that the ASP.Net team will be busy with porting the libraries to new netfx core and other stuff related to VS 2015. So there may not be major change coming up immediately.

Comment: We are actively working with Microsoft's OData team and have jointly discovered a number of bugs that they are working on so that the OData4 web api more closely matches the OData 4 spec.  I will post on the Breeze blog when we have a 'beta' release.